# shifting a piece of text down using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to shift a text label down by about 6px I am attaching the style:

```
.price-label{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-6px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="45" colspan="2" align="center"><p><span class="text">Name</span><span class="name-label"></span></p></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="price-label">54.67</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="28" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td height="45">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="28" bgcolor="#CC3300">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td height="112">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="28" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td height="22">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

Visually I want the 54.67 label to appear horizontally parallel - to the gap where the grey cell (top one) and red cell (second from top) meet. As the number represents that point in the bar to the left.

So if some other technqiue is better, please let me know, maybe I should be using DIVs would that give me more control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, then you're trying to straddle the border between two table cells which won't work. You'll need to consolidate the first two cells in the right column and then rowspan="2" the new cell with the number in it. Then top or bottom vertically align the text in the cell and add some padding-top until it's aligned properly.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to shift it ***down***, you need to shift it a **positive** 6px, not a negative 6px, and set the **top** property, not bottom

```
position: relative;
top: 6px;
```

Comment: better reasoning, but I don't feel messing around with position is the right way to go here - 'course we don't actually know :)

Answer (score 3):

Label is an inline element, margin/padding would only work when you make it a block (inline-block, block or float). Try this:

```
.price-label {
        padding:6px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline; }
```

Comment: Good answer.  This aspect is often forgotten with inline elements... +1

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using:

```
.price-label { margin-top: 6px; }
```

It's difficult to know more without some context of what else is around that table cell though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `padding-top:6px;` instead of positioning, which can get very messy with relation to sibling elements etc.. and has other-side effects.